Cross reference Language injected JavaScript in JetBrains IDEs
The current IDE I am using is Rider (ASP.NET Core C#)
How can I resolve these warnings for unidentified JavaScript functions/classes/members if they are declared in language injected variables?
The same issue occurs in PhpStorm, and I assume it happens in PyCharm as well.
public abstract class SelectorScript
{
    public static GlobalDefinition chooseProduct { get; } = new();

    public static ScriptFile File()
    {
        return new ScriptFile(
            /* lang=javascript */
            $$"""
              
                /**
                 * @param {string|Node|$Selector|Window} selector - element or selector
                 * @param {Document|Node} [baseElement] - base element
                 * @returns $Selector
                 */
                $S = (selector, baseElement = document) => {
                    return (new $Selector).$set(selector, baseElement);
                }
          """);
    }
}

Code Screenshot:

Warning Shown:



I've changed the tag from phpstorm to webstorm as it's more suited for JavaScript related questions (and it was better to keep other tags as is).



Regarding the actual issue -- I do not think it is really possible. Because AFAIK all injection fragments are treated as independent entries (at least in PhpStorm). I remember they were stating this in a few tickets a few years back. E.g. here, really long time ago or bit more recent here (it is about SQL language but still). Maybe somebody from JetBrains/Rider team can give you a more definite answer.

